# Rails date select parameter permit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I was using the following code to send date parameter to rails.

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <select class="form-control" id="years" name="user[birthday(1i)]">
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="months" name="user[birthday(2i)]">
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="days" name="user[birthday(3i)]">
    </select>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But the back-end receive like this

```
{
  "user"=>
    "birthday(1i)"=>"2018",
    "birthday(2i)"=>"8",
    "birthday(3i)"=>"13"
}
```

How to make it become a hash, so I can use `strong parameter` in rails.

EX:

```
 def update_params
  params.permit(:birthday)
 end
```

Comment: Try `params.require(:user).permit(:'birthday(1i)', :'birthday(2i)', :'birthday(3i)')`

Comment: Can I have a way to only put `params.require(:user).permit(:'birthday)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to store this as a `date` in your database and use `date_select` inside your form.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "birthday"
end
```

**controller**

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:birthday)
end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
        <%= f.date_select :birthday, {
            order: [:month, :day, :year],
            date_separator: "/",
            prompt: {
                month: 'mm',
                day: 'dd',
                year: 'yyyy',
            },
         } %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok, then you should be able to use `date_select`, i will update my answer to provide an example.